# react native Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: java, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

i'm trying to build this app, i hade many bugs in building this app on android and i fixed them one by one except this one it give me a hard time, i already tried all the solutions from google and stackoverflow but nothing worked for me.
anyway im working on a windows trying to build this app on android device.
here is the error that i get when i run react-native run-android

```
  - react-native-google-signin: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin
  - react-native-maps: https://npmjs.com/package/react-native-maps
Please notify their maintainers about it. You can find more details at https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/configuration.md#migration-guide.
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually:
  - @react-native-community/async-storage (to unlink run: "react-native unlink @react-native-community/async-storage")
  - react-native-android-open-settings (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-android-open-settings")
  - react-native-fbsdk (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-fbsdk")
  - react-native-firebase (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-firebase")
  - react-native-gesture-handler (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-gesture-handler")
  - react-native-google-signin (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-google-signin")
  - react-native-maps (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-maps")
  - react-native-sound (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-sound")
  - react-native-vector-icons (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons")
This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above. Going forward, you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink <dependency>" and it will be included in your app automatically. If a library isn't compatible with autolinking, disregard this message and notify the library maintainers.
Read more about autolinking: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 2378 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\android\app\src\main\java\com\kaalix\MainApplication.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
            new RNSoundPackage(),
                ^
  symbol: class RNSoundPackage
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\android\app\src\main\java\com\kaalix\MainApplication.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
            new AndroidOpenSettingsPackage(),
                ^
  symbol: class AndroidOpenSettingsPackage
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\android\app\src\main\java\com\kaalix\MainApplication.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
            new RNFirebasePackage(),
                ^
  symbol: class RNFirebasePackage
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\android\app\src\main\java\com\kaalix\MainApplication.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
            new AsyncStoragePackage(),
                ^
  symbol: class AsyncStoragePackage
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\android\app\src\main\java\com\kaalix\MainApplication.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
            new VectorIconsPackage(),
                ^
  symbol: class VectorIconsPackage
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\android\app\src\main\java\com\kaalix\MainApplication.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
            new RNGestureHandlerPackage(),
                ^
  symbol: class RNGestureHandlerPackage
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\android\app\src\main\java\com\kaalix\MainApplication.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
            new RNGoogleSigninPackage(),
                ^
  symbol: class RNGoogleSigninPackage
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\android\app\src\main\java\com\kaalix\MainApplication.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
            new MapsPackage(),
                ^
  symbol: class MapsPackage
C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\android\app\src\main\java\com\kaalix\MainApplication.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
            new FBSDKPackage()
                ^
  symbol: class FBSDKPackage
Note: C:\Users\hp\kaalix\kaalix_taxi_dev\android\app\src\main\java\com\kaalix\MainApplication.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
9 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: Looks like you manually performed linking.error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually:So try to unlink them(Steps are shown in the error message).

Comment: @Thakur yes i have tried that too, i unlinked all of them one by one but it didn't work